# Maven JBoss to Websphere JDK

Tags: java, maven, websphere, pom.xml

I want to shift my app from jboss to webshphere, having said that, thus i need to integrate websphere jdk to my project, is there are maven repo for websphere 7 that i can integrate to my pom.xml?

if none, how can i tell my pom.xml to just get my dependencies (websphere jdk) from local or through a repo manager?

```
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.ryan.commons</groupId>
<artifactId>Commons</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>StrutsExample Maven Webapp</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
        <artifactId>struts-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.10</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
        <artifactId>struts-taglib</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.10</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
<build>
    <finalName>StrutsExample</finalName>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no WebSphere artifacts in any public repos that I'm aware of.

However, WAS 7.0 uses a Java 6 JDK so you can just build with an Oracle Java6 JDK. Your application will be just fine if you do that (I did this successfully for many years).

You should probably change your servlet API version though, as WAS 7.0 is a Java EE 5 compliant application server which incorporates Servlet 2.5 (not 3.1).